# confusion related to arrays of arrays and iteration

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a local variable ID within my main method as follow :

```
    ID = new int[9];
    ID[0] = 245;
    ID[1] = 76644;
    //etc
```

I also have an arrayList of object , with the following constructor :

```
    public Songs( String songName, String artistName, Integer duration, double price) {

    this.songName = songName;
    this.artistName =artistName;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.price = price;
```

I initiated a 2d array as following :

```
   Songs reco[][];
    reco = new Songs [99999] [];         
    for (int i=0; i<99999; i++) {
        reco[i] = new Songs[20]; 
    }
```

What I am trying to do is use my variable ID as the first index of my 2d array, as follow :

```
    reco[ID[7]][1] = new Songs("Human", "The Killers", 288, 0.19); // ID always is a 5 digit number
```

So that i can skim through my 2d array, using the [ID[x]] as my reference in order to add the different values of duration i might come accross.

assuming the following 2d arrays :

```
     reco[ID[7]][0] = new Songs("Better Now", "Post Malone", 239, 0.25);
    reco[ID[7]][1] = new Songs("Human", "The Killers", 288, 0.19);
    reco[ID[0]][2] = new Songs("Smells like teen spirit", "Nirvana", 214, 0.28);
```

the expected outcome should be :

```
     "Customer:" [ID[7] total song duration is 239+288
     "Customer:" [ID[0]] total song duration is 214
```

Problem is, whatever loop i manage to fabricate, i end up with a null pointer error, as i am comparing [ID[x]][v] to [ID[x][v+1], calling a get() method on each, eventually reaching the null value.

Hope my problem is clear enough.

best to all

(i am aware one can make the numbers to iterate with less important with a hash function, although this is not the problem i want to adress right now)

Comment: You need to check the indices you are using, maybe a bad/unexpected index somehow got in there.  So now would be a good time to learn how to use a debugger.  With regards to your suggestion to use a map, that's what I would recommend here.

Comment: Would suggest using a singular class name for entities. E.g instead of naming the class `Songs` just name it `Song` (because an instance does just represent 1 song and not multiple)

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, debugging seems like a wise tool to have. Do you have any specific ressources in mind I could use ? Cheers ! Lino, thanks for the heads-up !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The null pointer exception is caused by accessing your array filled with null Elements by default. You are using elements like

> reco[ID[7]][1] = ...

without checking if the index 7 in ID array is an element or null.

If you want to create a really long Array like new `Songs[99999]` you should use a List and Iterators so there will be no reserved space in memory for that really long Array of 
"99999 Songs"

> ```
> Songs reco[][];
>     reco = new Songs [99999] [];         
>     for (int i=0; i<99999; i++) {
>         reco[i] = new Songs[20]; 
>     }
> ```

It's much easier to create a ArrayList or List and fill this up with a List of songs like:

```
List<List<Songs>> songs = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Songs>>();
```

Then you can iterate throught the list like:

```
for(List<Songs> tempSongsArray : songs)
{
   for(Songs tempSong : tempSongsArray)
   {
      //Code using tempSong as Songs Element
   }
}
```

Using list should be null-pointer safe cause the length of a list <==> elements in the list

Comment: Thanks for the comment; although i did try to iterate through both arrays and arrayList, i'm stuck in a scenario where i can't seem to have the correct syntax for the enhanced loop. Using a classic loop has got me stuck at either n-1 or n+1 (n being my number of arrays); and nested for loops gives me all the permutations (e.g 1->2, 1->3 when all i need is 1->2, 2->3).

Comment: actually am not able to reproduce the syntax you gave; nor can I find it on https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/using-enhanced-for-loops-with-your-classes. Is the article outdated ? I am very tired, i must be making the most obvious mistake haha